# What does this mean?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, sentence

What does the following sentence mean?

Self-serving bias beckons us not to false modesty but to a humility that affirms our genuine talents and virtues and likewise of others.

closely looking at the word humility and its meaning in the sentence.

Comment: Here's the complete context: http://edge.org/response-detail/10256

Comment: [on hold] *humility*, the quality or state of being humble.

Answer (score 1):

The passage quoted in the question is untrue if taken by itself.  [In context](http://edge.org/response-detail/10256) it reads:

> Being mindful of self-serving bias beckons us not to false modesty, but to a humility that affirms our genuine talents and virtues, and likewise those of others.

It is awareness of self-serving bias that so beckons;  self-serving bias itself has no such effect.

The phrase “beckons us not to false modesty” means that being aware of self-serving bias will not cause people to engage in false modesty.  That is, such awareness should not lead one to downplay one's actual skills, but should instead promote an egoless attitude of recognizing the true skills of oneself and others.